# Replace line feed (LF) with space but not affect carriage return (CR)

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove line feeds (LF) and replace with space and not affect the carriage returns (CR)?

I've tried the below but it also removes the carriage returns:

```
import fileinput
import sys

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

replaceAll("hold1.csv","\n","\s")
```

The input text would be something like this with | as a separator:

```
field1 | field2| field3 some textLF

more textLF

more text|field4 | field5 CR
```

Which I would like to see in the format of:

```
field1 | field2| field3 some text more text more text|field4 | field5 CR
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not your replacing code removes the carriage returns. Python, by default, *normalises line endings* when opening files in text mode; a feature called [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines). See the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> When reading input from the stream, if `newline` is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated.

You want to use the `newline=''` mode. Unfortunately, the `fileinput` module *doesn't support combining `inline` and `openhook`*, so you'll have to create your own backups to re-write the files:

```
import os

def replaceAll(file, searchExp, replaceExp):
    backup = file + '.bak'
    os.rename(file,  backup)
    with open(backup, 'r', newline='') as source, open(file, 'w', newline='') as dest:
        for line in source:
            if searchExp in line:
                line = line.replace(searchExp, replaceExp)
            dest.write(line)
```